# images upload when "insert" is used, but doesnt when "update" is used

Tags: php, mysql, image

```
$image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']); 
$image= file_get_contents($image);
$image= base64_encode($image);
$studentid = 1; $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
 mysql_select_db("secure_login",$con);
$qry="INSERT into images (name,image,studentid) values ('$name','$image','$studentid')";
$result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
```

Here, I've tried to insert images to MySQL. When I change the `insert` to query to `update`, the whole code falls apart and I can't fix it.

I know this is the basic syntax:

```
$qry="UPDATE images SET name = $name, image = $image, studentid=$studentid";
```

But then this doesn't work.

Comment: use `WHERE` in update query

Answer (score 1):

You insert a new row in a table. You UPDATE an existing row. So, whe you run an UPDATE query you have to specify what row you are updating. You can't just replace INSERT with UPDATE.
Update your code with:

```
$qry="UPDATE images SET name = '$name', image = '$image', studentid='$studentid' WHERE id='$rowid'";
```

Also note that in your query you should wrap values with '' to be sure on how mysql will handle them.

Answer (score 0):

your update query would be

```
$qry="UPDATE images SET name = '".$name."', image = '".$image."', studentid='".$studentid."'";
```

This query update your whole table you use `WHERE` clause to update only specific column